# PLINQ WithDegreeOfParallelism Delay?

Tags: c#, .net, plinq

I want to execute a network based task (with a possible long timeout) on multiple peers simultaneously.

So i have the following code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(hosts, i => SomeLongRunningNetworkTask(i));
```

I noticed that from the sixth task on the execution is delayed for ~ 1 second.

So i changed the code to:

```
hosts.AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(64)
                .ForAll(i => result.Add(SomeLongRunningNetworkTask(i)));
```

but the result is the same.

Output (on a Quad-Core):

```
Start: 44,00 ms
Start: 44,00 ms
Start: 44,00 ms
Start: 44,00 ms
Start: 44,00 ms
Start: 1025,06 ms
Start: 2024,12 ms
Start: 3024,17 ms
Start: 4024,23 ms
Start: 5024,29 ms
...
```

Is there an easy way to use PLINQ without this weird behavior, or am i missing something ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplicationParallelTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private DateTime Started { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // for testing: All Subnet IP's: 
            var ips = new List<IPAddress>();
            for(int i=1 ; i< 255 ;i++)
                ips.Add( IPAddress.Parse( "192.168.10." + i ));

            var result = new Program().ExecuteAll(ips);
        }

        private List<Object> ExecuteAll(List<IPAddress> hosts)
        {
            Started = DateTime.Now;
            var result = new List<Object>();

            //Parallel.ForEach(hosts, i => SomeLongRunningNetworkTask(i));
            hosts.AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(64)
                .ForAll(i => result.Add(SomeLongRunningNetworkTask(i))
                );

            return result;
        }

        private Object SomeLongRunningNetworkTask(Object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(Started).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F2") + " ms");
            Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("End: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(Started).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("F2") + " ms");
            return new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WithDegreeOfParallelism` doesn't means it will use that much thread. It is only for setting an upper bound (TPL will decide how many thrad to use depending on your system configurations).

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep() will not produce results that are representable for real code. If you want to optimize network code, use the that network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your threads call `Thread.Sleep` they are busy waiting and can't handle other of your hosts.
My guess is the `ThreadPool` realizes it needs more resources and goes and creates more threads.

Try maybe running the test after setting [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a bigger number.

Edit:
As @henk commented. This almost never is a good idea.

Comment: SetMinThreads  is the direct solution to the problem as presented. It is however a blunt, application wide instrument and probably not the best solution.